# read from text file in qml qt/quick

Tags: c++, qml

I have a program to preview images that store every image's path (all images are in my computer) in text file. first i open text file and read line by line images paths and store to a list then i source image to the list[i],(for i=0 to numbers of images). it returns to me some error like this:

```
QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:///D:/QtApp/Gui_qml_app/res/1.png%0D
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 800c000d
```

this is my text file:

```
file:/D:/QtApp/Gui_qml_app/res/1.png
file:/D:/QtApp/Gui_qml_app/res/2.png
file:/C:/Users/info/Desktop/wall_images/3.png
```

and this is my code:

```
           property int i: -1
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
            request.open('GET','in.txt')
            request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

                 list = request.responseText.split('\n');
                }
            }
            request.send()
    item.source =String(list[i+1])
i++;
```

can every one help me?

Comment: I think my problem is  %0D that attached end of images path but i don't know haw can i Getting rid of that

Comment: That's likely a newline character that is being included when you read each line from your text file - you need to find a way to strip it from the URL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DirectShow` error tells us that you're running on Windows and most of the time, newlines are coded with `\r\n` on this platform.

Before assigning the item source path, remove the extra  `\r`:

```
list[i+1] = list[i+1].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
item.source = String(list[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your answer. I change my code in below and it's work pretty good

```
    property int i: -1
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
            request.open('GET','in.txt')
            request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

                 list = request.responseText.split('\n');
                }
            }
            request.send()
    item.source = String(list[i+1]).substring(0,String(list[i+1]).length-1)
i++;
```